# Website crawler for big sites that crawl site status, title and h1

Tags: web-crawler

i would like to crawl big sites (for example with 1 000 000 internal links) and thats too much on tool that i use now (Screaming Frog and Xenu). Do you know about any PHP crawler, that sends data about links to database and can provide solution for me?

Or do you have any ideas how to solve this problem when i wanna overview of all internal and external links on website with site statuses and titles? Any paid script or something (but no online tools like http://info.deepcrawl.co.uk/pricing/usd that is really expensive for me and paid monthly).

I have a server on which to run script.

I need something like this:
http://codecanyon.net/item/jseo-web-crawler-for-search-engine-optimization/full_screen_preview/8770392
But this scirpt can only crawl very few links and does'nt support MySQL database saving.

Thanks for suggestions,
Filip

Answer (score 0):

first create a php file and include the DOM parser php file into it.
Then into that

```
$toGet = "your website link";
$innerHtmlPage = file_get_html($toGet);
```

the below code is for finding the tag or attribute from that page of website and then you can get the content using diff. DOM parser functions like plaintext,innertext,outertext,etc.

```
foreach ($innerHtmlPage->find('body .paginationtop .data-display-view-all span') as $innerelement) {
      $pages = trim(strip_tags(substr($innerelement, strpos($innerelement, "of") + 2)));
 }
```